# Passing param to report in new exception reporting with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I'm refactoring my exceptions to enjoy [the improvement done in Laravel 5.5](https://laravel-news.com/custom-exception-reporting)

Now, it is great, but I use an external bug tracker: [Sentry](https://sentry.io), and I need to pass the variable `protected $sentryID;` defined in `Handler` class into the view.

How should I do it, if I get this param in my render method in each custom exception?